# Rotatating page using PDFBOX library having issue

Tags: java, java-8, pdfbox, java-7

I have a pdf having 6 pages and I have rotated the second page to 90 degrees using the pdfbox (Version 2.0.29) and input as `ByteArrayOutputStream` that is successfully rotated but again when I am taking rotated pdf as input and rotating another page of the same pdf then the page which I mentioned 2nd time is getting rotate and rest all the pages are going to original form. But it should preserve my first rotate page that the issue??

can anybody help??

I tried everything passing file,changed the file but nothing worked.

```
PDF.rotatePage(baos, "", 4, NGPDF.PageRotation.ROTATE_90);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using PDFBox? There are no classes `PDF` or `NGPDF` in PDFBox...